# jQuery animate not doing anything

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I’m trying to animate a background color on a h1 on hover with jQuery because of IE, but nothing happens. I checked my javascript sources, the two links are correct. I have tried with other properties (height, top…), on other divs, but nothing ever happens. I joined the parts of my code I think are relevant. Does anyone see what’s wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/WP-remivincent/wp-content/themes/data.vortex/js/ColorAnimation/jquery.animate-colors-min.js"></script>

<script> 
        $('.infos-une').hover(    
        function(){
            $(this).animate({backgroundColor: 'rgba(190,52,19,0.8)'});
        },
        function(){}  
    ); 
    </script>

</head>

<style>          // In my style.css file
.infos-une {     // it’s a <h1>
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
color: #fff;
display: block;
height: 130px;
padding: 20px;
position: absolute;
    top: 311px;
width: 301px;
}
</style>

<section>
<div class="articles-une-container">
<div class="articles-une">
<div>
    <a href="http://localhost/WP-remivincent/article-title/">
        <img width="341" height="341" src="illustration.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="illu-3">
        <h1 class="infos-une gd rokkit">Article title</h1>
    </a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried wrapping your code in document ready?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // your code here ... 
});
```

[Jquery document ready](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Comment: This can always be done shorter with `$(function(){/*code*/});`

Comment: Oooh that’s embarassing. Sorry about that, I’m sort of a beginner to javascript and jQuery…
Thanks a lot though, this had been bugging for a while now!

Answer (score 0):

This script tag is in the `head`

```
<script> 
    $('.infos-une').hover(    
        function(){
            $(this).animate({backgroundColor: 'rgba(190,52,19,0.8)'});
        },
        function() {}  
    ); 
</script>
```

As a result the `body` tag is not loaded when that script is interpreted. So `$('.infos-une')` won't return any nodes. You could try moving the script tag to the end of the document, or wrap the script in `$.ready`, like

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.infos-une').hover(    
            function(){
                $(this).animate({backgroundColor: 'rgba(190,52,19,0.8)'});
            },
            function() {}  
        );
    });
</script>
```